# Toolbar not fixed in my layout - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a  class **Include_toolbar** for setting my toolbar. My toolbar sets alright but when i push the toolbar up, it moves upwards and disappears off my recyclerView.

What could be causing this in my layout please?

**Include_toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
            android:background="#B22222"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/counter_text"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <include
            layout="@layout/Include_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_large_icon_height" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Remove attribute `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from `Toolbar` and try again.

Comment: Thank you.. that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove attribute `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from `Toolbar`.

**Try this:**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
        android:background="#B22222"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/counter_text"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```